# Stop(); in nested movie clip doesn't work AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip on my timeline, which I then move on main timeline using classic tween from one side to another. I do not want that mc to loop so once the animation inside it finishes it should stop and all frames should be visible until the tween on main timeline finishes. To stop it from looping I added new keframe with stop(); at the end inside the movie clip. But it doesn't work, the movie clip keeps looping. I have changed the property type on first frame in the main timeline from movieclip to Graphic so that I can preview the movie clip in the timeline. In previous versions of Flash it worked always fine, but in CC the stop(); is ignored. 
I know AS won't work with Graphics, but as far as the AS is inside that Graphic that shouldn't matter. Could anyone explain it to me and provide some solution please?

Comment: The stop needs to be on the last frame of the main timeline.

Answer (score 2):

Your animation is happening on the root timeline so you need to put your stop(); on the last keyframe on your main time line. Or create the animation inside your movieclip and put the stop(); on the last keyframe in there instead and put the movieclip on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code it works 100%

Paste the below code your main time line and called MovieClip_name.stopAllClips();

```
MovieClip.prototype.stopAllClips = function():void {
    var mc:MovieClip = this;
    var n:int = mc.numChildren;
    mc.stop();
    for (var i:int=0; i<n; i++) {
        var clip:MovieClip = mc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
        if (clip) {
            clip.stop();
            clip.stopAllClips();
        }
    } }
```